# Make the content stronger and more confident

Tags: color, page-layout, design-principles, presentation-design

I'm preparing an important pitch tech. The previous designer made the following design. I'm fine with the overall-style.

However, for the slides "Business Development", I would like the content (the texts, the big circle and the three circle insides) to look more apparent, strong, and confident. I feel the image on the right grabs somehow the focus of the readers. But it's not too bad to have an illustrative image somewhere in the slide.

Similarly for the slide "Business Model".

I'm not a designer. Could anyone suggest any idea about how to relocate/change/resize/split the images on the right so that the real content looks stronger and more confident?

[image]

[image]

Comment: IMHO, in print the images to the right of the slides are helpful in catching the readers attention. On the other hand, if you're presenting to a captive audience a slide show, then the right side images are a distraction.

Comment: If you are not a designer, as you admit, it might be a very bad idea to start changing the work of one. Either hire her again to tackle these issues with her; or hire a new designer and have them take a shot at it. In the latter case, make sure you have or acquire the rights to edit the design.

Comment: The pages you don't show enlarged are all *completely crammed* with content. If this deck is going to be presented, it should rely on the presenter to tell most of the content, and only give keywords in the slides. If you want your design to display confidence, be minimalist. Do realise that lots of text on your slide distracts the viewer: they will start reading it, and are no longer listening to the speaker.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is all really a matter of *opinion* and one's own design aesthetic.

I would remove those right side images. The images on the right are superfluous and don't add anything. In fact there are several slides using random images as apparent "filler". Adding images for the sake of adding images is a bad idea. If it's *business* there's no need to add unrelated imagery - it won't "sell" the content better. Any image use should be *directly* related to the content being presented.

For the Model slide, the image would appear to be used as a page-filler. Then on the Development slide it would appear other content is somewhat condensed to allow for the image - note how text on the left actually hits that blue arrow. And text on the right is not all aligned the same to "make room" for the image.

In addition, on the grey background white can be used to push content more.

These are quick and dirty....

[image]

Are these less eye-catching without the images? Perhaps. But the *content* is much clearer and focused.

Overall, **color could *greatly* be unified across all the slides** - use 2 or 3 colors, then varying tints/shades of those colors if needed. As opposed to 8 or 9 different colors. Honestly, the abundant colors makes it appear as if most of the slides were pulled from somewhere else, some other presentation. Overall, there's little cohesiveness across the presentation. In fact, these 2 specific slides and the head shot slide are the only slides which appear to possibly be from the same presentation. Unifying the colors across slides will go a *long* way to making *everything* seem more "solid" and impactful.

I'm not really sure about the free-pro-business graphic. The connected "chain" circles makes it appear as though all 3 account types are linked to one another. That may be the case. If it isn't that graphic may be better off being replaced to remove the connotation that they are integrated with one another.

Answer (score 3):

Those right side images illustrate nothing of your actual content. Some of the images may well sit in your title slide to catch the attention, but on slides which try to tell some facts or ideas they do nothing but disintegrate your presentation. Remove them and make the rest bigger, thicker, more colorful etc... if that's needed.

A presentation is the sum of the shown material and the plausibility of the person who performs in front of the audience. A person who cannot do more than change slides and at best read them aloud is useless.

Do NOT insert images which  present nothing of the actual content - no matter how finely crafted they are. Such  images make a weak performer to look even weeaker and thin content to look even thinner. Anything which earns to be called an illustration must supplement the content.